# Q Learning Algorithm Issue

Tags: algorithm, matlab, reinforcement-learning, q-learning, temporal-difference

I'm trying to do a simple Q learning algorithm, but for whatever reason it doesn't converge. The agent should basically get from one point on the 5x5 grid to the goal one. When I run it it seems to have found the most optimal way however it doesn't converge and I can't figure out why. Any help would be appreciated. I feel like there is one little mistake somewhere so that's why I'm looking for a fresh set of eyes.

Code:

```
function Q=ReinforcementLearning

clc;

format short

format compact

% three input: R, alpha and gamma

% immediate reward matrix; 

% row and column = states; -Inf = no door between room

R=[-inf,-inf,    0,    0, -inf;

   -inf,-inf,    0,    0, -inf;

      0,   0, -inf, -inf,  100;

      0,   0, -inf, -inf, -inf;

   -inf,-inf,    0, -inf, 100];



gamma=0.8;            % learning parameter
alpha=0.5;
oldQ = 0;


Q=zeros(size(R));      % initialize Q as zero

q1=ones(size(R))*inf;  % initialize previous Q as big number

count=0;               % counter


for episode=0:50000   

   % random initial state

   y=randperm(size(R,1));

   state=y(1);




   % select any action from this state

   x=find(R(state,:)>=0);        % find possible action of this state

   if size(x,1)>0,

      x1=RandomPermutation(x);   % randomize the possible action

      x1=x1(1);                  % select an action 

   end


   MaxQ=max(Q,[],2);

   %Q(state,x1) = R(state,x1) + (gamma * MaxQ(x1)); %old function that works perfectly (converges)

   Q(state,x1)=  oldQ + alpha * (R(state,x1)+ (gamma * MaxQ(x1)) - oldQ); % new one that I need to implement

   oldQ = Q(state,x1);



   state=x1; %#ok<NASGU>


   %Q = round(Q);


   % break if convergence: small deviation on q for 1000 consecutive

   if sum(sum(abs(q1-Q)))<5 & sum(sum(Q > 0))

      if count>1000,

         episode        % report last episode

         break          % for

      else

         count=count+1; % set counter if deviation of q is small

      end

   else

      q1=Q;

      count=0; % reset counter when deviation of q from previous q is large

   end

end


%normalize q

g=max(max(Q));

episode

if g>0, 

   Q=100*Q/g;
   roundQ = round(Q);
   roundQ

end
```

Comment: Did you try with larger values of alpha (up to 1-epsilon)?

Comment: Yeah I have and it doesn't seem to affect it much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT:

The problem is here:

```
Q(state,x1)=  oldQ + alpha * (R(state,x1)+ (gamma * MaxQ(x1)) - oldQ);
```

you are updating each **Q(state,x1)** with an **oldQ** value, whereas this value should be updated by its own previous value **Q(state,x1)** before taking this action. Do you see it? it is better to have a matrix for **Q** and save the previous  values that you can use them here. As I can see you are using the same **oldQ** for all the **Q**s.

Actually you can load the previous values from **q1** and use them instead of **oldQ**.

Comment: Ok let me try to reduce the threshold and I will see how it goes. By the way it wasn't supposed to be:

if sum(sum(abs(q1-Q)))<5 & sum(sum(Q > 0)) but if sum(sum(abs(q1-Q)))<0.0001 & sum(sum(Q > 0))

I forgot to change that before pasting it here.